# Yii url management issue

Tags: php, regex, yii, url-rewriting

I'm developing a web application using Yii Framework and I'm having a little problem with url rewriting.

The issue is with the last rule in the code below. It was supposed to turn **`localhost/app/category/some-friendly-url-category-name`** (this part would appear in the browser) into **`localhost/app/category/view/id/some-friendly-url-category-name`**

It works fine when the category name is **only one word**, like: *vehicles*.
But it doesn't work when it has **more than a word**, like: *children-stuff*

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            'category/<id:[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+>' => 'category/view',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: what error actually throws  during more than a word .

Comment: Just that it could find the action. But as Samuel Liew said, it was only the position of the rule. Specific rules must be above general rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the hyphen in the ID:

```
'category/<id:[A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -]+>' => 'category/view',
```

A simpler solution would be:

```
'category/<id>' => 'category/view',
```

---

Also, do note that you have to place this specific rule above the general (default) rules.

Move the category rule above the `<controller>` ones. Otherwise, your app would try to find a `actionChildrenStuff()` in your CategoryController, for example.

Usually I would add new rules above those three general ones.

Comment: None of these worked :( Its weird. Do you think it could be any misconfiguration?

Comment: Forgot to mention that you have to place specific rules above general rules. Move that category rule above the `<controller>` ones.

Comment: Ohh, I feel so stupid right now! That was it! Thank you so much!